# Problem with a list validation in Haskell

Tags: validation, haskell

I'm creating a program that validate the time.
I have the following code:

```
data TimeError
  = WrongHour Int
  | WrongMinute Int
  deriving (Eq, Show)

lookHour :: Int -> Validation [TimeError] Int
lookHour n
  | n < 0 = Failure[WrongHour n]
  | n > 23 = Failure[WrongHour n]
  | otherwise = Success n

lookMinute :: Int -> Validation [TimeError] Int
lookMinute n
  | n < 0 = Failure[WrongMinute n]
  | n > 59 = Failure[WrongMinute n]
  | otherwise = Success n

lookTime :: (Int, Int) -> Validation [TimeError] Time
lookTime (h, m) = Time <$> lookHour h <*> lookMinute m

lookAllTimes :: [(Int, Int)] -> Validation [TimeError] AllTimes
lookAllTimes [] = Success (AllTimes [])
lookAllTimes (x:xs) = AllTimes <$> lookTime x <*> lookAllTimes xs
```

The function `lookAllTimes` is suppose to use `lookTime` in a list of times to return the results, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the definitions of `Time` and `AllTimes`, but I'm going to guess they were as follows:

```
data Time = Time Int Int deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype AllTimes = AllTimes [Time] deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Given them, the problem is in the cons case of `lookAllTimes`. Specifically, you're not calling `(:)` there to put the list back together, and you're also not removing the `AllTimes` wrapper from the tail. Replace your last line with this one:

```
lookAllTimes (x:xs) = (\y (AllTimes ys) -> AllTimes (y:ys)) <$> lookTime x <*> lookAllTimes xs
```

You can also simplify the whole `lookAllTimes` function by taking advantage of the `Traversable` instance for lists, though, like this:

```
lookAllTimes :: [(Int, Int)] -> Validation [TimeError] AllTimes
lookAllTimes = fmap AllTimes . traverse lookTime
```

That basically means "do `lookTime` on each list element, then wrap the succesful result in `AllTimes`".